# Proper way to validate array inside angularjs form?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form. This form contains array of products i.e

```
[{"productId":"12121212","count":5},{"productId":"22222222","count":6}]
```

What i need is to :

1. Validate the form on client and disable submit when any of product array fields are invalid.

Can i use validators like i work plain form fields and check like:

```
myForm.product[i].productId.$invalid, 
myForm.product[i].productId.$error.required
```

?

2. Validate the form on server when submit and pass back errors to client. Now i attach service prop 'error', but it seems not common way to angularjs validation.

Plunker link:https://plnkr.co/edit/kbLs3SJE5ybNxIvo3ynq

Any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: if user disables JavaScript at any stage, your application should still stay consistent. I think that is why *both* validations are necessary. You can have the JavaScript validation, which will help the user enter valid data(and prevent unnecessary API calls), but a back-end code is necessary to ensure that data reaching back-end is valid too.

Comment: I change question cause i don't get what i want

Answer (score 0):

It is best to validate the input fields on client side first. To disable the submit button based on validation you can use `ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"` on submit button. This will work for HTML validations on input fields like required, ng-minlength, ng-maxlength, etc.

However for complex validations on field, you can write a function and call it: `ng-disabled="isFormValid()"`. This function will iterate through all values and check if they are valid.